# Highcharts with SAP in .net

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts, abap

I would like to know the scope of using High charts in ASP.NET with SAP as back end.

How can I populate the SAP values to Highcharts in ASP.NET?

Comment: Have you tried to get the SAP data as a JSON? I think it could be a solution.

Comment: Thanks Federico. Any other alternate solution you could find

Comment: Hi, I'd use that option of their format to JSON, it's easier to handle in my opinion because Highcharts would prefer that format too.

Comment: Maybe you can check this:
https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3550748

Comment: Yes this works fine!! Thanks

Comment: The SAP link above was about ABAP `CALL TRANSFORMATION` to convert data to JSON, so based on OP "this works fine", I changed the SAP tag into ABAP, because SAP tag is ambiguous.